# Generate number of columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, foreach, html-table

I've got these two functions working fine, but I'm realizing the number of columns should be generated dynamically. Would you be able to help me do that? Thanks! ^_^

```js
function getTableData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var lr = ws.getLastRow();
  var lc = ws.getLastColumn();
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,lr-1,lc).getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}

function generateTable(dataArray){

var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

  dataArray.forEach(function(r){

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var col1 = document.createElement("td");
    col1.textContent = r[0];
    var col2 = document.createElement("td");
    col2.textContent = r[1];
    var col3 = document.createElement("td");
    col3.textContent = r[2];
    row.appendChild(col1);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    row.appendChild(col3);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
```

Comment: a `for` loop perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Store your dynamic column length in a variable and create a nested loop

Sample:

```
var colNumber = 5; 
dataArray.forEach(function(r){
   var row = document.createElement("tr");
   for(var i = 0; i < colNumber; i++){
     var col = document.createElement("td");
     col.textContent = r[i];
     row.appendChild(col);
   }
   tbody.appendChild(row);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are near, just put loop on till the no of columns you have lc, keep adding td in one row and than after loop add that tr to main table